# ClassCastException inserting data with Oracle XSU in OpenLiberty

Tags: java, oracle, open-liberty

We are migrating a legacy application from IBM WebSphere to OpenLiberty. Some functionalities use Oracle XSU to perform operations with the database.

I have managed to obtain the Oracle-specific connection by performing an unwrap operation over the `java.sql.Connection`.

The error is raised when trying to insert data through XSU:

```
oracle.xml.sql.OracleXMLSQLException:
com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.v42.WSJdbc42PreparedStatement cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement
```

My server.xml:

```
<library id="jdbcLib">
        <fileset dir="C:\Users\uC260112\.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc6\11.2.0.1.0"/>
</library>

<dataSource id="gcmsXAWIPDS" jndiName="jdbc/gcmsXAWIPDS" type="javax.sql.XADataSource">
        <jdbcDriver javax.sql.XADataSource="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource" libraryRef="jdbcLib"/>
        <properties.oracle URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@c588cwegcmd03.int.xxxx.com:1521/xxxxx.int.xxxxx.com" password="xxxxxx" user="xxxxxx"/>
        <connectionManager maxPoolSize="100" minPoolSize="1"/>
</dataSource>

<enterpriseApplication id="xxxxx" location="xxxxx-1.0.ear" name="xxxxx">
        <classloader commonLibraryRef="jdbcLib"/>
</enterpriseApplication>
```

Obtain and unwrap the connection:

```
conId = myXAPool.obtainConnection(null, null);
Connection connection = myXAPool.getConnection(conId);

OracleConnection oracleConnection = connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
```

Try to insert using XSU:

```
OracleXMLSave sav = null;

    try {
        sav = getNewOracleXMLSave(oracleConnection, tableName);
        sav.setRowTag(rowDelimiter);
        sav.setDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        sav.insertXML(xsuXml); //Exception here
    } catch (Exception ex) {
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: Can you post the stack related to this exception?  That would help debug this issue. Also what is myXAPool, it doesn't look like a traditional DataSource.  Are you somehow wrapping the DataSource class yourself?

Comment: Also should be mentioned that ojdbc6 is out of support.

Comment: @KyleAure, the exception comed from the insertXML method and does not have a stackTrace. It only states that the parent exception is "java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.v42.WSJdbc42PreparedStatement cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement."
myXAPool is a class that saves the different DataSources available in the application but manages the standard javax.sql.DataSource.
I have test with ojdbc7 and same error occurs.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the problem is that Oracle's XSU library is not unwrapping the PreparedStatements (thanks @njr), I have found a solution that works.

Build a proxy over the oracleConnection, and pass it to the XSU library instead of the actual oracleConnection:

```
OracleConnection oracleConnection = connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class); 

OracleConnection proxy = (OracleConnection) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                        OracleConnection.class.getClassLoader(),
                        new Class<?>[]{OracleConnection.class},
                        new OracleConnectionInvocationHandler(oracleConnection));

OracleXMLSave sav = null;

        try {
            sav = getNewOracleXMLSave(proxy, tableName);
            sav.setRowTag(rowDelimiter);
            sav.setDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

            sav.insertXML(xsuXml);
```

That way, I can intercept the calls that the XSU library makes to the prepareStatement method, and do the unwrap before returning the object to the library. This is the proxy handler:

```
public class OracleConnectionInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private final OracleConnection target;
    private SPELogger systemLog = null;

    public OracleConnectionInvocationHandler(OracleConnection target) {
        systemLog = AppLogger.getInstance();
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        if ("prepareStatement".equals(method.getName())) {

            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = (PreparedStatement) method.invoke(target, args);

            systemLog.logInfo(this, "Making PreparedStatement unwrap through OracleConnectionInvocationHandler");

            return preparedStatement.unwrap(oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement.class);

        }

        return method.invoke(target, args);
    }
}
```

In the meantime, I'm still in contact with Oracle to see if there is an XSU library that handles this properly. But the solution with the proxy works perfectly.

Comment: That's a nice, very creative way to work around the Oracle bug. Hopefully you will also be successful in convincing Oracle to fix their code so that the workaround can become unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the ClassCastException is coming out of `oracle.xml.sql.dml.OracleXMLSave` (the stack will confirm that), you should open a case against Oracle for attempting to direct cast to `oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement` rather than using `unwrap` to obtain it from statements it prepares from the supplied connection.  It looks like you are doing the right thing with respect to using `unwrap` in your code, but the Oracle code needs to do likewise in its code for the prepared statement.

Comment: Thank you @njr. 
Yes, I think maybe you are right. The `PreparedStatement` seems to need to be unwrapped as well. 
Since the `oracle.xml.sql.dml.OracleXMLSave` class comes from `xsu12-11g.jar`, I am wondering if can exist any upgraded library that manages this correctly.

Comment: I have posted a solution that works for me, thanks to your clarification @njr